# How to find out which files on my Debian system are not from any deb packages?

Tags: debian, dpkg

I have Debian testing (wheezy/sid) on my home PC. Some time ago I have been careless enough to install some software with `make install` and `./install.bin` and similar :) Now I want to know which files on my system were installed in such a way, i.e. the files, which do not belong to any currently installed .deb packages.

I know I could write a script using `dpkg -l` and `dpkg -L ...` and `find -name ...` and similar, but I wonder if anyone has done it already.

(Just could not think of a good Google query for this question :)

Comment: see
http://serverfault.com/questions/238191/how-to-find-files-in-a-debian-system-not-installed-or-created-by-dpkg
and
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18038/how-to-list-files-and-folders-that-are-not-maintained-by-any-deb-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dpkg -S can probably help you. It returns 0 if a given file or file pattern is matched and includes the package name in the output, and returns 1 if it was not found in any installed package.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it definitely simplifies the task. But anyway, I still hope that someone has a full-blown script to do the task.